# Simplifying a Regular Expression

Tags: java, regex

I have a really simple question (punny right).

What is the simplest form of this regular expression?

```
(((0|1)*(00)(0|1)*)((0|1)*(11)(0|1)*))|(((0|1)*(11)(0|1)*)((0|1)*(00)(0|1)*))
```

I'm creating a regular expression that accepts a language for all binary strings that contain the substrings 00 and 11 (in any order).

The expression I have now works, but I'm sure it can be simplified.

Comment: Why? It doesn't need to be simplified. It will get reduced to a canonical form when the pattern is compiled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is almost the same regex. I only converted the `(0|1)` into `[01]`, added a `[01]*` to the left and right shared for both cases (11 first or 00 first) and removed some parenthesis that were not necessary:

```
[01]*(00[01]*11|11[01]*00)[01]*
```

---

### Steps to reproduce

1. Stating with

   `(((0|1)*(00)(0|1)*)((0|1)*(11)(0|1)*))|(((0|1)*(11)(0|1)*)((0|1)*(00)(0|1)*))`
   `__^^^^^_____^^^^^___^^^^^_____^^^^^______^^^^^_____^^^^^___^^^^^_____^^^^^___`
2. Replace all `(0|1)` by `[01]`

   `(([01]*(00)[01]*)([01]*(11)[01]*))|(([01]*(11)[01]*)([01]*(00)[01]*))`
   `_______^^^^____________^^^^_______________^^^^____________^^^^_______`
3. Remove parenthesis around `(00)` and `(11)` as you do not want to capture this group and you do not have a `*`, `+`, `?` behind the parenthesis. Therefore it is not required because of ambiguity.

   `(([01]*00[01]*)([01]*11[01]*))|(([01]*11[01]*)([01]*00[01]*))`
   `_^____________^^____________^___^____________^^____________^_`
4. Remove yet more parenthesis that does not solve any ambiquity:

   `([01]*00[01]*[01]*11[01]*)|([01]*11[01]*[01]*00[01]*)`
   `________^^^^^^^^^^_________________^^^^^^^^^^________`
5. Collapse `[01]*[01]*` into `[01]*` which means exactly the same.

   `([01]*00[01]*11[01]*)|([01]*11[01]*00[01]*)`
   `_^^^^^_________^^^^^___^^^^^_________^^^^^_`
6. Extract common prefix and suffix `[01]*`

   `[01]*(00[01]*11|11[01]*00)[01]*`

Comment: Good answer. Thank you. If you don't mind, could you tell me how you knew where to eliminate parenthesis?

Comment: I updated my answer which now includes **steps to reproduce**. Hope that helps.